# SQL Format with Leading characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

I want the customerId to be formatted like this "TUH000000" my SQL already spits out an int of 1, 2, 3 etc.  So if the customer id is 1 I want it to print TUH000001 so on and so forth.

this is my code so that spits out everything I need in the table, minus the formatting.  Any ideas?

```
SELECT r.CustomerID,r.Year AS [Year],r.UnpaidBalance AS [UnpaidBalance],ci.FName AS [FName], ci.LBName AS [LBName],ci.IdType AS [IdType],ci.Id AS [Id],ci.OwnerId AS OwnerId, a.Line1 AS [Address1], a.Line2 AS [Address2], a.City AS [City], a.StateId AS [State], a.Zip AS [Zip]
FROM #ThisReport r
LEFT JOIN #CustomerInfo ci ON r.CustomerID = ci.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN Address a ON ci.mAddID = a.AddressId
ORDER BY CAST(r.CustomerID as int) ASC;
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  One way is:

```
select prefix + right(replicate('0', 6) + cast(x as varchar(255)), 6)
```

I'm not sure which columns you want to combine.  Pehaps:

```
select 'TUH' + right(replicate('0', 6) + cast(CustomerId as varchar(255)), 6)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I was close but I kept trying to put the 'TUH' with the 0's as a string.  It was odd.  thanks for the push!